# Looking for help to construct a Regex for pattern matching

Tags: regex

I'm looking for help in making a regex to match and not match a series of name patterns if anyone can help with that.

Here's a list of cases I want to match/ not match :

```
// Should Match :
_class
c-class
_class-like
_class--variation
_class__children
_class__children--variation
c-custon-button-test
_class__lol--test
c-my-button-super-style
_class--variation-like

// Should not Match :
class
c--class
_class---variation
_class----variation
_class__test__test
_class--variation__children
_like
c-like
noMargin
no-Margin
_no-Margin
no-margin
_class-like__children
_class-like--variation
```

For now I came up with this regex :

```
^(c-|_)([a-z]+)(__|--|-)?([a-z]+)(-{0,2}[a-z]+)+(-?(([a-z]-?)+|(like))$)
```

Which almost work but I still got a match on some case which shouldn't match and I'm afraid I'm struggling to find how to sort the last cases.

(Here's a link to regex101 with unit test and match case: https://regex101.com/r/HNAUpd/1/)

edit : I forgot to mention, about the word "like" it's a keyword in my pattern and can only be found at the end of the string and cannot be the sole word in the string.

edit 2 : As for the rules of matching they're as follow :

- A string can start only with "_", "c-" or "js-".
- the following word can be anything but not the word "like" and should not be anything else that letter in the range [a-z] and only in lowercase.
- The word "like" can only be the last one of the string and must not be the only one in the string.
- Words can be separated by "--" or "__".
- If the string starts with "c-" the word can then be separated with "-" in addition to the previous separator.

The purpose of all this is for a CSS class/id matcher for a linter.

If anyone can help me with this it would be awesome :)

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that "like" is a reserved keyword I want to set apart from the matches, It can only be found at the end of the string but cannot be the only word in the string.

Comment: Simply providing examples of what should and should not match is not enough. You need to tell us the rules for accepting a match. I can come up with several patterns that match everything in the first list and reject everything in the second list but are very likely not to satisfy your _actual_ requirements. Please [edit] the question and provide more details. Additionally, you should mention what programming language (or regex flavor) you're using. You selected JavaScript in regex101; is that what you're using? If so, please use the relevant tag.

Comment: So is `_foobar` a valid match? And why is `c-like` invalid?

Comment: I edited the main message with the rule set (sorry to have forgot about it).

_foobar is valid, c-like is not as I want to keep like as a reserved keyword which can't be alone in the string (not counting the "starting" pattern")

Comment: @Matthias The last bullet point doesn't make much sense. Based on your pattern and example, I think you want the "__" separator to be used only once and the remaining separators should be either "-" or "--". Is that correct? Anyway, see my answer below. I'm adding an explanation in a second.

Comment: @41686d6564 It's correct the single hyphen is used as a word separator, the double hyphen is used to indicate a variation of the previous statement in the string (like _button and _button--red) where "red" is the variation of the "_button". (hope this help clarify a little and not confusing the thing more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
^(?!.*[\-_]like[\-_])(?:c-|js-|_)(?!like$)(?:[a-z]+(?:__|--?))?[a-z]+(?:--?[a-z]+)*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTw3B7/2)**

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of the string.
- `(?!.*[\-_]like[\-_])` - Doesn't contain the word "like" between two separators (only at the end of the string).
- `(?:c-|js-|_)` - Either "c-", "js-", or "_" at the beginning of the string.
- `(?!like$)` - Not immediately followed by the word "like".
- `(?:[a-z]+(?:__|--?))?` - (optional) one or more a-z letters followed two underscores or one or two hyphens.
- `[a-z]+` - One or more a-z letters.
- `(?:--?[a-z]+)*` - Match one or two hyphens followed by one or more a-z letters, and repeat zero or more times.
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. Shouldn't have used `\b` because underscores are used as separators. Fixed :)

Comment: @41686d6564 verry good solution and thanks a lot for the update :)